# creating objects from text file data. no viable overloaded '=' error

Tags: c++, file, input, polymorphism, overloading

I'm basicly trying to tokenize a string from a file and create an object using the tokens as parameters for the object.

I need to be able to make a new object for each line in the file.

But I get the error no viable overloaded '='

```
 string tokens[8];
int i =0;
int j=0;


vector<Package *> myPack[5];

while (file.good()){
    getline(file,buffer);
    cout<< buffer<< endl;

    string token, text(buffer);
    istringstream iss(text);
    cout <<endl;
        while (getline(iss, token, '|')){
            cout << token << endl;
            tokens[i]=token;
            i++;
}

myPack[0] = new Package(tokens[0] ,tokens[1],tokens[2],tokens[3], stod(tokens[4]), stod(tokens[5]));
j++;
}
```

error occurs here

```
  myPack[0] = new Package(tokens[0] ,tokens[1],tokens[2],tokens[3], stod(tokens[4]), stod(tokens[5]));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector<Package *> myPack[5];` is an array of five (empty) vectors, not a vector with five `Package*` elements.

The latter looks like `vector<Package *> myPack(5);`.

Comment: Thank you so much! that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `myPack` vector has a length of 0, so `myPack[0]` (accessing the first element in the vector) is an error.

You have to `push_back` your Package object to insert it.